# file explorer and selecting mp3 file to send to media player android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am struggling with this issue for a few nights now without any solution (i'm a new programmer)

I have this "load" button that opens up the file explorer and from there I can choose mp3 file.

my problem is that after I selected the file... it won't play in the media player.

This is the code I use to open the activity:

```
        loadbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.putExtra("audioUri",audio);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);

        }
    });
```

this is the code for the media player which is not playing anything. but if I will put a file from R.raw.something - it will work..it is not playing the audioUri

```
                seekBar.setEnabled(true);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,audio);
            mediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(mediaPlayer.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed));
            mediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(mediaPlayer.getPlaybackParams().setPitch(speed));
            totalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    stopPlayer();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: maybe this will help? 
    `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stringPath);`

Comment: @Quinn - could you please be more specific and help me understand where should I add it?

Comment: just before you start the mediaPlayer, and replace stringPath with the file URI

Comment: @Quinn didn't work. May be the problem, is that my audiouri has no actual Uri?

Comment: The audioURI should look something like "file:///path/to/file.mp3"

Comment: @Quinn  How can I be sure it caught it?
Should I use onActivityResult or something?